# How to keep two fields in Sync in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have to keep a form field and another attribute of an Angular 2 component in sync. (Because of certain limitations I cannot bind both fields to the same attribute).

Here's my template:

**Field #1**

```
<datepicker [(ngModel)]="dob" [minDate]="minDate" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></datepicker>
```

**Field #2 (Form element)**

```
 <input  [formControlName]="question.key" [id]="dob" [type]="text"/>
```

Field #1 and #2 need to be in sync.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **attribute binding** to bind regular input's value to datepicker's value:

```
<datepicker [(ngModel)]="dob" [minDate]="minDate"
[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></datepicker>

<input  [formControlName]="question.key" [attr.value]="dob" [id]="dob" [type]="text"/>
```

Here's [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KEOi61pjAVk1vlGOBIld?p=preview) I created with the above example. Read more about attribute binding [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#other-bindings).

Comment: What is attr.value in this context?

Comment: @user6123723 `[attr.value]="dob"` means you are binding input's attribute `value` to value of variable `dob`. `[attr.attributeName]` is just Angular's syntax for binding to element's attributes.

Comment: so 'attr' is dob? Shouldn't this be [question.key.value]="dob"? Thank you.

Comment: @user6123723 No, no, `[attr.value]="dob"` means that you are binding input's attribute value, not `formControlName`'s value. Is this not working for you, are you getting errors?

Comment: [attr.value]="dob"  means "..Binding input's attribute value". This statement is not clear for me. I've literally used [attr.value]="dob" and it doesn't work. I checked the docs in your post and there's no such thing as attr.value. I understand that I need to bind "dob" to the input field. But that should look something like [input_field_name.value]="dob" where input_field_name is the name of the input field. I'm not sure how to generate a plunkr for this

Comment: @user6123723 OK, I created plunker for you, check it out: http://plnkr.co/edit/KEOi61pjAVk1vlGOBIld?p=preview

Comment: Thank you so much!